# is there a function in a c lib to print data packets similar to Wireshark format (position then byte by byte)

Tags: c, networking, printing, wireshark

Is there a function in a C lib to print data packets similar to Wireshark format (position then byte by byte)

I looked up their code and they use trees which was too complex for my task. I could also write my own version from scratch but I don't wanna be reinventing the wheel, so I was wondering if there is some code written that I can utilize. Any suggestions of a lib that I can use?

*The data I have is in a buffer of unsigned ints.

```
0000 01 02 ff 45 a3 00 90 00  00 00 00 00 00
0010 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00
0020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 ... etc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe look at hexdump? not sure how they do it but it's probably much simpler than wireshark since wireshark parses whole packets and gathers a lot of information from it.

Comment: You could also have a look of the source of the `od`, `xd`, `hexdump` tools in GNU sources, if you really do not want to write it from scratch, but it is so simple that I am not sure that it is worth it...

Comment: You may want to look at `libpcap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt such a specific function exists in the libC, but the system is rather simple:

```
for (unsigned k = 0; k < len; k++)
{
    if (k % 0x10 == 0)
        printf("\n%04x", k);
    if (k % 0x4 == 0)
        printf(" ");
    printf(" %02x", buffer[k] & 0xff);
}
```

Replace the first modulo by the line length, and the second by the word length and you're good (of course, try to make one a multiple of the other)

EDIT:

As I just noticed you mentioned the data you have is in a buffer of unsigned ints, you will have to cast it to an unsigned char buffer for this part.

Of course, you can do it with an unsigned buffer with bitwise shifts and four prints per loop, but that really makes for cumbersome code where it isn't necessary